# Uncaught Error: TypeError: 21: type 'JSInt' is not a subtype of type 'bool' dart

Tags: flutter, dart

- I write a function that takes two arrays as a parameter and the function merge the arrays, tried to print the merged list but I have the error **Uncaught Error: TypeError: 21: type 'JSInt' is not a subtype of type 'bool'** and tried to make the function to return the list and I print it in another function but I still had the same error, i think the error because the function return type but I tried it as void and yes I know void not work because I have if and it return list  or List but not working, or because the editor I use the dart bad online
- there's any suggestion to make the function more efficiant for this problem?

```
  var list = [];
  var arr1Item = arr1[0];
  var arr2Item = arr2[0];
  var i = 1;
  var j = 1;

  if (arr1.length == 0) {
    return arr2;
  }
  if (arr2.length == 0) {
    return arr1;
  }
  while (arr2Item || arr1Item) {
    if (!arr2Item || arr1Item < arr2Item) {
      list.add(arr1Item);
      arr1Item = arr1[i];
      i++;
    } else {
      list.add(arr2Item);
      arr2Item = arr2[i];
      j++;
    }
  }
  print(list);
}
void main() {
  reverseString([1, 2, 5, 31], [21, 5, 8]);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unlike in JavaScript, you can't simply check for a truthy value of an array. The code `if (arr)` will throw an error, because `arr` doesn't evaluate to a `bool` value.

I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to achieve here, but some thoughts regarding efficient Dart / Flutter:

To merge two arrays, you can simple add the arrays.

```
final array1 = [1, 2, 3];
final array2 = [4, 5, 6];

final joinedArray = array1 + array2;
print(joinedArray); // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
```

Instead of checking for `length == 0`, use `isEmpty`.

```
if (arr1.isEmpty)
```

The reversing of an array can be done using the inbuilt `.reversed` method.

```
final reversedArray = array1.reversed;
```

Comment: thanks for your effort, i don't try to check the true value of an array? can you explain to me where the error?

Comment: At `while (arr2Item || arr1Item)`.  Taking another look, you're checking if the `int` is truthy, but that also doesn't work in Dart. If you want to make sure something isn't `null`, use `arr2Item != null || arr1Item != null`